# WebRTC - Reusing connections

Tags: webrtc

Say we have the following:

1. `Peer1` joins, creates `RTCPeerConnectionA`
2. `Peer2` joins, creates `RTCPeerConnectionB`
3. `SDP`/`ICE` handshakes occur, connection is established, streaming is happening

   4A. `Peer2` loses connectivity and rejoins

   4B. `Peer2` refreshes the browser

**What should `Peer1` do in `4A` and `4B`?**

With `4A` the same `RTCPeerConnection` object is available for the peer to use - is there any work that needs to be done to completely repair the connection?

In `4B`, `Peer1` has maintained one end of the connection but `Peer2` is starting out from scratch.  Can `Peer1` re-use the `ICE` candidates and `localDescription` to repair the connection with the new `RTCPeerConnection` on the other end, or does it also need to create a brand new instance of `RTCPeerConnection` and reinitiate handshakes, onicecandidate, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4a: this is done with an ice restart. https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/restart-ice/ is an example of how to do this.

4b: a new peerconnection will be needed as the refreshed tab will not have the crypto credentials to decode the old stream.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there any guidance around knowing when 4a and 4b happen?  For 4b I'm considering creating a new connection if I receive an `localDescription` from a peer that doesn't match the `remoteDescription` I have already set for them (by comparing sdp strings)... does that sound like an okay approach?

Comment: ice restarts should typically be done when the ice connection state goes to 'failed'. Documentation is very sparse, https://medium.com/the-making-of-appear-in/ice-restarts-5d759caceda6 has some examples

Doing a new connection... this depends very much on your signaling protocol. Comparing SDPs is unlikely to work.